# can i make the treeview of tkinter begins from the right side?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

I'm new in python, I make a `treeview` in `tkinter` showing the data of workers with Arabic language saved in a `sqlite` file, and because the number of columns is 12 column, made a horizontal scrollbar, I need a help to make the scrollbar begins from right to left when showing the `tkinter` without moving it, like right to left direction (page layout) in excel.

[image: scroll begins from the right like that]

Comment: Try calling `root.after(10, tree.xview_moveto, 1.0)` before `root.mainloop()` (assume `root` is the root window and `tree` is the treeview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by `tree.xview_moveto(1)`.